# how to find the probability of each class with respect to test data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here I am using naive Bayes classifier, how to find the probability of each class respect to each test data set?

```
#Import Library of Gaussian Naive Bayes model
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np

#assigning predictor and target variables
x= np.array([[-3,7],[1,5], [1,2], [-2,0], [2,3], [-4,0], [-1,1], [1,1], [-2,2], [2,7], [-4,1], [-2,7]])
y = np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4])
#Create a Gaussian Classifier
model = GaussianNB()
# Train the model using the training sets
model.fit(x, y)

#Predict Output
predicted= model.predict([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(predicted)
```

Comment: Did you do some research on it?

Comment: I want to know if any inbuilt function is present for it? https://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/

Comment: I think google is a better place to do that

Comment: What is the point of including a `print(predicted)` command here without  showing its *output*?

Comment: print(predicted) is showing the output as [3 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the documentation for better understanding https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

```
predict(X)  Perform classification on an array of test vectors X.
predict_log_proba(X)    Return log-probability estimates for the test vector X.
predict_proba(X)    Return probability estimates for the test vector X.

>>> model.predict_proba([[1,2],[3,4]])
array([[0.53258224, 0.46741776],
       [0.15119031, 0.84880969]])
```

Comment: [0.53258224, 0.46741776] this is the probability of [1,2] test sample but where is class respect to these probability [0.53258224, 0.46741776] values?

Comment: if n training data set is present then n probability should be there respect to one test sample data and n number of probability for another test sample data with their class labels

Comment: how may I get it?

Comment: class is the highest probability you get the zeroth index is for probability of '3' and first index is for probability of '4' whichever is higher is your class in this case, probability is not for test cases but rather for the redicted tag, try changing the training and test data, you will understand

Comment: here two probability is given for one test data sample, which probability belongs to test sample?

Comment: for example, test sample [1,2] and their probability is [0.53258224, 0.46741776] as a result, which contains two probability, what probability belongs to sample [1,2]?

Comment: probability is for the label, for the input [1,2] probability of its being 3 is 0.53 and for 4 is 0.46, As of label 3 prob is higher your pred label is 3.